# In Redux, why do we set the initialState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

According to the Redux documentation, it seems to be a standard practice to set an `initialState` on your reducer. However this `initialState` needs to be maintained and if the state is being populated based on an API response, then you may have the initial state out of sync with the API response. This is especially true in cases where the state is made up of nested objects.

Is it to avoid null-checking (sometimes the initial state is set to `null`), are there any performance benefits? Does it improve code readability?

Taken from [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers):

```
const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL,
  todos: []
}
```

Then in our reducer we may have an action which replaces the value in the state (for example based on an API response). Such as:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TODOS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: action.todos
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

However the same behaviour may be achieved without using an `initialState`, by checking the state in the component (or selector).

```
const MyComponent = ({todos}) => { 
  if (!todos) { // if we do not have an initialState, todos will be undefined if SET_TODOS hasn't been called
    return null;
  }

  return <div>{todos.map(n => ...)}</div>
}
```

If the API returns a new property (`notes`), we would need to update as follows:

```
const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL,
  todos: [],
  notes: []   // <-----
}

function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TODOS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        todos: action.todos,
      })
    case SET_NOTES:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        notes: action.notes,
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This is further complicated in cases when you have nested objects. If the `todos` has a child property `subtasks: []`, why are we not setting an initial state for it?

Comment: Wouldn't todo be an empty array if SET_TODOS hasn't been called ?

Comment: I doubt there are performance implications. Code just tends to be more predictable if your data structure stays consistent.

Comment: If would be an empty array if we use `initialState`, but if we do not use an initial state we can simply check for `undefined`. (updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more of a convenience than anything else. I highly doubt there is any performance implications. Also while in my personal opinion it is cleaner to add all the properties you expect upfront, you are not really required to add it to the initial state. You can simply add it when returning the new state, obviously if you're using typescript this is a different story.

```
const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL,
  todos: []
  // notes: []  you don't necessarily need to add it to the initial state 
}

function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case SET_TODOS:
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
            todos: action.todos,
            notes: action.notes   // <-----
          })
   default:
      return state
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an initial state helps to have "cleaner" code. Like Brian Thompson said in the comments, code is more predictable if your data structure stays consistent.

It is also recommended (by some ppl) to avoid having multiples returns in one function. It may not be the best perf-wise, but it might be the easiest to read.
So having to do an early return in your component might not be the cleanest way to achieve the behavior your want.

That being said, if your implementation works, why not use it ? Well i think it's best when working as a team to stick to the conventions as much as possible.